# Data from MySQL CHARSET problems, please look the image!

Tags: php, mysql, html, http, utf-8

If ISO-8859-1 then (HTML Text: GOOD, MySQL Data: BAD)
if UTF-8 then (HTML Text: BAD, MySQL Data: GOOD)

What can I do to solve it?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get the encoding of your HTML page and that of the database data in sync.

UTF-8 is probably the best way to go. If you save your HTML page as UTF-8 (there should be a setting in your editor/IDE) things should work fine.

Make sure your page sends the correct `content-type` as well.

Comment: content-type UTF-8, mysqli_charset( "UTF-8" ), mb_http_output( "UTF-8" ), I use eclipse... I set the encoding for the files: UTF-8 ..

Comment: @Cris you seem to have ISO-8859-1 characters in your file, there's no other explanation for what you show on the left hand side